# Inserting Inline Images in Word Online

Tags: office-js

I am trying to insert inline images in a content control in Word from the Word Api in OfficeJS. This all works fine but in Word Online I get some rendering issues. It seems the document is not syncing until I click it. Also if I click in different parts of the document some elements in my document seem to disappear.

For inserting the images I use the `contentControl.insertInlinePictureFromBase64(image, "Replace");`

Here's [a link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2oqz6b6lohd0lbn/Word%20Online%20Images.mp4?dl=0) to a video that shows the issue.

Comment: URL for the video is not accessible

Comment: Updated it, should work now

Comment: Did you try resizing before inserting? These issues are due to size.

Comment: I removed our resizing code and the issue remains